# Server is busy when trying to restore previous version for SharePoint Designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

We are using 2010 workflow in sp2013 and when trying to restore previous version of workflow facing

[image]

How to fix this issue?